# Calculating the probability of a result after measurement using Ry, Rz, and Rx matrices

Tags: qiskit, measurement

**Broadly**: I have noticed on the qiskit developer (assessment) exam there are many questions asking to calculate the probability after measurement however I generally have no idea how to do this without using code (for any gate).

**Specifically**:
Given this code fragment, what is the probability that a measurement would result in $|1\rangle$ if the state is prepared with the following code:

`qc = QuantumCircuit(1) qc.ry(2 * math.pi/4, 0)`

I.e.: how do we answer questions like these in an exam setting using our knowledge of cosine and sine?

**Note** that I am referring to and broadening Sample Question 2 - IBM Quantum Developer Certification which can be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBaVOE5pcaI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Ry$ gate is described by following matrix
$$
Ry(\theta) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos(\theta/2) & -\sin(\theta/2) \\
 \sin(\theta/2) & \cos(\theta/2) 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

If your qubit was in state $|0\rangle$ before application of the gate, operation $Ry(\theta)|0\rangle$ leads to state
$$
Ry(\theta)|0\rangle =
\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos(\theta/2) & -\sin(\theta/2) \\
 \sin(\theta/2) & \cos(\theta/2) 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\theta/2) \\ \sin(\theta/2)
\end{pmatrix}=
\cos(\theta/2)|0\rangle + \sin(\theta/2)|1\rangle.
$$

Since probability of measuring a particular state is square of absolute value of the probability amplitude, we have
$$
P(0) = |\cos(\theta/2)|^2 \\
P(1) = |\sin(\theta/2)|^2.
$$

In your case $\theta = 2\pi/4 = \pi/2$. So, $P(0) = \cos^2(\pi/4) = 1/2$ and $P(1) = 1/2$.

Try yourself to calculate probabilities $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ for state $Ry(\theta)|1\rangle$.

Simiarly you can do the calculation for application of $Rx$ and $Rz$ gate. See matrices defining the gates [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RXGate.html) for $Rx$ and [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RZGate.html) for $Rz$.

Answer (score 0):

The way I guess the probability and know the correct answer is to imagine a Bloch sphere, and imagine how the gate effect the arrow of the bloch sphere.

also can look at these two cheat sheet from Qiskit Slack # qiskit-cert-exam

- https://qiskit.slack.com/files/U039SFMFWP9/F03L9HY1Z52/bell_and_ghz_states.pdf
- https://qiskit.slack.com/files/U039SFMFWP9/F03L489AV8V/quantumgates_cheatsheet.pdf

I suggest playing with these two websites while learning quantum gate

- https://algassert.com/quirk
  Example:  https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22Y%5E%C2%BD%22%5D%2C%5B%22Y%5E%C2%BC%22%5D%2C%5B%22Measure%22%5D%5D%7D
- https://javafxpert.github.io/grok-bloch/
  Example of how to imagine question 2:
  [image]

Comment: Note that Bloch sphere is useful only for one-qubit state. Try to calculate probabilities after application of e.g. Toffoli gate on three-qubit state. :-)

Comment: The links for the slack pdfs seem to be broken :(

Comment: @epsilonolispe just join qiskit slack channel, and looking for the file, if you do, it should show file details at the right side bar., after you click the link

Comment: @epsilonolispe you can use `qiskit.visualization.visualize_transition` for trace animation of Bloch sphere